# Get Frame Rate of Android using Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, frame, frame-rate

I am able to get the frame rate of the Android system using the following answer in  Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8908035/4190159

However, being new to Kotlin I was wondering how can I get the frame rate of Android system using Kotlin code? (my app is using Kotlin instead of Java)

The code as follows is not working for me:

```
fun getFrameRate(): String {
        val timeElapsed1: android.os.SystemClock = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        val timeElapsed2: android.os.SystemClock = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        val frameTime = 1000.0 / (timeElapsed2 - timeElapsed1) 
        return frameTime
}
```

Comment: You appear to be comparing two time instants one after another, shouldn't you be comparing between two times recorded by different calls of `Choreographer.postFrameCallback()`?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thank you for your reply. I am new to Kotlin development and not sure how to get the framerate. Any suggestions on how to call Choreographer.postFrameCallback() to get framerates?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve by getting the 'frame rate' of the system. I recommend reviewing the Google IO video: [Drawn out: How Android renders (Google I/O '18)](https://youtu.be/zdQRIYOST64) and [UI Jank Detection](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/jank-detection) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()) returns a `long`, not an `android.os.SystemClock`:

```
fun getFrameRate(): String {
        val timeElapsed1: Long = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        val timeElapsed2: Long = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        val frameTime = 1000.0 / (timeElapsed2 - timeElapsed1) 
        return frameTime
}
```

or you can simply omit the types and let Kotlin infer them for you:

```
fun getFrameRate(): String {
        val timeElapsed1 = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        val timeElapsed2 = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        val frameTime = 1000.0 / (timeElapsed2 - timeElapsed1) 
        return frameTime
}
```

Lastly, you'll need to convert `frameTime` to a `String`:

```
fun getFrameRate(): String {
        val timeElapsed1 = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        val timeElapsed2 = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        val frameTime = 1000.0 / (timeElapsed2 - timeElapsed1) 
        return frameTime.toString()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Currently, using your code snippet I am getting the following error: "Unresolved reference: SystemClock". :( But was resolved by using android.os.SystemClock instead. However, the output (returned value) of frameTime.toString() is Infinity.

Comment: What are the values of `timeElapsed1` and `timeElapsed2`?

Comment: SystemClock.elapsedRealtime().toString() is coming to Infinity. How to resolve this?