How to get the Current FPS of the Screen of android using the ADB
I am working with the Android Platform, I want to know the FPS of the screen of my app.
I am struggling to calculate the current FPS of the android screen, when my app is running. Because, sometimes it is lagging and hanging a lot, so at that time I want to measure the FPS and compare it with the normal FPS.

I'd look to the Android profiler and System Trace - which includes statistics on all UI frames and in particular janky frames.

duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907917/how-to-measure-fps-on-android-during-app-development
